# Delete Post on Facebook Ruby Curl:Easy

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curl, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using curl easy library to make http delete requests to Facebook graph to delete a post.
 Code snippet is below:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{id}?access_token=#{token}"
curl = Curl::Easy.new(url)
result = nil
retries = 2
while (!result || curl.response_code != 200) && retries >= 0
    result = curl.http_delete
    retries -= 1
end
return result
```

Facebook returns "not valid request" each time. I have verified access_token in facebook debugger. 
What am i missing here? Can someone please help?

Comment: What API endpoint are you trying to hit? I don't see any that start with an id in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2

Answer (score 0):

You should add `/post` to your `url` as [per the reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post#deleting):

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/post/#{id}?access_token=#{token}"
```

Comment: How are you getting the `id`? Is it a valid facebook post id?

Comment: yes. I have verified the same in facebook explorer.